# Pinkish or pink

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Let's let's say a girl has opted out of a beauty treatment too soon. Because of this, the beneficial effect of it is not fully achieved.

> 1. The newly healed tissue is not as **pinkish** as it should be, because of the early laser treatment removal. (My answer)

Or

> 2. The newly healed tissue is not as **pink** as it should be, because of the early laser treatment removal.

I think sentence1 is correct here, but a native said sentence2 is the correct one? I need to know it further because "pink" is noun while "pinkish" is the adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pink** is an adjective in this case, as is **pinkish**. Both are grammatically correct, though "**pinkish**" is a vague term ("**-ish**" on the end is a colloquial term that means "kind of" or "roughly").

So semantically, saying "my tissue is not as *roughly pink* as it should be" doesn't really make sense. I'd use "**pink**" in this case.

Comment: If the objections of the treatment is to achieve a color that is “similar to pink but not exactly pink”, like coral or crimson, then “pinkish” is okay.

Comment: @whiskeychief That's true, and as I said it would be grammatically correct. But even in that case, it still sounds contrived to me with that wording. Though I accept that might be the aim of the sentence.